# adding first row to to a csv

Tags: c#, .net, csv, console-application

Having the following function:

```
string chargeMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMM");
var fileCreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
string fileCreationTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss");
string constVal = "MLL";
string fileType = "HIYUV-CHEVRA";
string[] values;
string header, sumRow;
string line, compId;
string inputFile = "records.CSV";

Dictionary<string, System.IO.StreamWriter> outputFiles = new Dictionary<string, System.IO.StreamWriter>();

using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("D:\\" + inputFile, Encoding.Default))
{
    header = file.ReadLine();
    
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        values = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());
        compId = values[3];
        
        if (!outputFiles.ContainsKey(compId))
        {
            sumRow = constVal + "-" + fileType + "-" + (String.Format("{0:00000}", Int32.Parse(compId))) + "-" + chargeMonth + "-" + fileCreationDate + "-" + fileCreationTime;
            string outputFileName = constVal + "-" + fileType + "-" + (String.Format("{0:00000}", Int32.Parse(compId))) + "-" + chargeMonth + "-" + fileCreationDate + "-" + fileCreationTime + ".CSV";
            outputFiles.Add(compId, new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\" + outputFileName));
            outputFiles[compId].WriteLine(header);

        }
        outputFiles[compId].WriteLine(line);
    }
}

foreach (System.IO.StreamWriter outputFile in outputFiles.Values)
{
    outputFile.Close();
}
```

Which will create csvs based on dictionary's keys/values.
anyways, for each CSV I want to add a row in the FIRST line which is not in a format of the other rows..
somehting like:

```
line1 aaaabbbbcccc
line2 1 2 3 10 100
line3 2 2 3 10 100
```

I have no idea how to do that since Im "pulling" data from a dictionary and the line has nothing to do with it. Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: *" I want to add a row in the FIRST line"* do you mean add the "line1 aaaabbbbcccc"? could you simply do this before the `while` with a `WriteLine`. Also, this code is confusing, actually you don't need a dictionary to verify if "a string is already read", you could use a `HashSet` instead for example

Comment: what do you mean I can do that with writeline? lol I dont want a console.Writeline, I want to write inside the csv. theres no such method as file.writeline / append/ something....

Answer (score 0):

```
outputFiles[compId].WriteLine(constVal + "-" + fileType + "-" + (String.Format("{0:00000}", Int32.Parse(compId))) + "-" + chargeMonth + "-" + fileCreationDate + "-" + fileCreationTime + ".CSV");
```

added the following line, it works now. thanks.